# Pass component via props in react that matches type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to define a props so that a component can be passed. But the component should have a few properties defined for it to be valid.

What I am doing now:

```
type ComponentProps = {
    onClose: () => void
}

interface IProps {
    component?: React.ReactElement<ComponentProps >
}

const Tester: React.FC<IProps> = ({component}) => {
    return null
}
```

```
const ShouldNotBeValid = () => (
    <div>Invalid</div>
)

const ShouldBeValid:React.FC<ComponentProps> = () => (
    <div>Valid</div>
)
```

```
const App = () => (
    <Tester component={ShouldNotBeValid } />
    <Tester component={ShouldBeValid} />
)
```

How can I write this logic so that only component with matching types can be passed?

Comment: you mean components with onClose on its props? because technically Typescript handles type validation for you... you don't have to test it, it will fail on build time.

Comment: Yes it is only types validation in typescript i am looking for.

Comment: The code is just to illustrate. Not the actual code case.

Answer (score 0):

Making `ShouldNotBeValid` props' type incompatible with `IProps` should do the trick:

```typescript
type EmptyProps = {
  [k: string]: never
}

const ShouldNotBeValid: React.FC<EmptyProps> = () => (
    <div>Invalid</div>
)
...
const App = () => (
  <>
    <Tester component={ShouldNotBeValid} /> {/* Type 'FC<EmptyProps>' is not assignable to type 'FC<ComponentProps>' */}
    <Tester component={ShouldBeValid} />
  </>
)
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wyvygw)

---

As a sidenote. The problem would be much easier to grasp when component types are written as plain functions instead of `React.FC` helpers.

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wzy4Em)

---

### Explanation

Why does typescript allow to substitue `Tester`'s `component` prop typed as `(props: IProps) => JSX.Element` with `({}) => JSX.Element`?

Function subtyping in typescript works as follows:

```
Notation: S <: T
How it reads: S is a subtype of T
              T is a supertype for S
What it means: S can be safely used in a context
               where a value of type T is expected

---

type F1 = S1 -> S2 // function from type S1 to type S2
type F2 = T1 -> T2


F1 <: F2
  <=>
S1 -> S2 <: T1 -> T2
  <=>
T1 <: S1 and S2 <: T2
```

As you can notice the result type's relation `S2 <: T2` has the same direction as functions' one `F1 <: F2` while the arguments relation `T1 <: S1` is inverted. It happens due to pretty advanced feature called [variance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).

So from typescript's point of view `({}) => JSX.Element` is a valid substitution (subtype) for `({ onClick: () => void }) => JSX.Element` function:

```typescript
type NotValidProps = {}
type ValidProps = { onClick: () => void }

declare function NotValid(props: NotValidProps): any
declare function Valid(props: ValidProps): any

type A = typeof NotValid extends typeof Valid ? true : false 
     // type A = true //   NotValid <: Valid
type B = ValidProps extends NotValidProps ? true : false     
     // type B = true // ValidProps <: NotValidProps
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nal86w)

Since the functions' result types are the same, one should break argument types' subtyping to break the functions' subtyping.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesn't really solve my issue though. 
What I am looking for is a way to declare the component type on props on the Tester component. 
It is more of a react types issue than purely just typescript. Thus why I can't simplify into functions.